# Run models using DBT CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, dbt

I'm trying unsuccessfully to run DBT models using DBT cli on GCP cloud shell.

Here're the details -

profile.yml

```
default:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      dataset: my_dataset
      job_execution_timeout_seconds: 1000
      job_retries: 1
      location: EU
      method: service-account
      priority: interactive
      project: my_project
      threads: 4
      type: bigquery
      keyfile_json:
        type: service_account
        project_id: XXXXXXX
        private_key_id: vasljasgjaspogjsapodgjasaklgjsagjs
        private_key: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYYYYYYY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
        client_email: XXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        client_id: 9577623947510934752394752
        auth_uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
        token_uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
        auth_provider_x509_cert_url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
        client_x509_cert_url: https://www.googleapis.com/EWPOTEOIGH;LSGJJ;LJgcpsecuritykey-gbl-ww-pd.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The dbt_profile.yml file -

```
# Name your project!
```

```
name: 'my_new_project'
```

```
version: '1.0.0'
```

```
config-version: 2
```

```
# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
```

```
profile: 'default'
```

```
# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
```

```
model-paths: ["models"]
```

```
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
```

```
test-paths: ["tests"]
```

```
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
```

```
macro-paths: ["macros"]
```

```
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]
```

```
target-path: "target"
```

```
.......
```

```
......
```

```
.......
```

This is how I run the dbt model → dbt run --select model_name

Below is the error I get -

```
(dbt) user@cloudshell:~/git_repo$ dbt run --select my_model
12:57:32  Running with dbt=1.4.4
12:57:32  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- models.my_project.example
12:57:32  Found 130 models, 5 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 784 macros, 0 operations, 1 seed file, 91 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
12:57:32
12:57:32
12:57:32  Finished running  in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.01 seconds (0.01s).
12:57:32  Encountered an error:
Database Error
  expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: The `Database Error` makes me think you should check either the logs or BigQuery to see what query is failing and see if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Agree with the above. The `Database Error` is poor error handling, but it could be an authentication issues from the CLI with your BQ project. +1 to checking if the query appears in BQ personal/project history